# unable to connect apache server after reboot

Tags: linux, apache, reboot

I'm new to Linux 
I have an urgent Issue,
I have an apache server, 
I had to reboot it but now I can't connect to it.
Any Ideas?
My code

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: What distribution of linux is this?

Comment: are you sure it's started ? `ps aux | grep apach`. You can try `apachectl start ` or `/etc/init.d/apache star`

Comment: is your apache server configure as a service. does it running after reboot at all?

Comment: Thanks all of you for the quick response. I have apache 2 linux server. I tried ssh username@domain.com and I got nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: I don't have any physical access to the server... I even can't connect

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the assistance, It was a problem with the host...
Not my side.
cheers.